# Eloquent relation with where condition on model attribute

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

I have two models `Student` and `StudentRevision` with `Student` model having `hasMany` relation with `StudentRevision` model. I have defined a `hasMany` relation in `Student` as

```
public function revisions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(
        'StudentRevision',
        'sid'
    );
}
```

I have a field in **students** table (Student model) which references current revision of student from **student_revisions** table.

The table structure is something like this.

**students** sid srid name ....

**student_revisions** srid sid batch ....

Now i want to define `hasOne` relation with `StudentRevision` model which references `current revision` linked with `Student`. Currently I have defined this relation as:

```
public function current()
{
    return $this->hasOne(
        'StudentRevision',
        'sid'
    )
    ->where('srid', $this->srid);
}
```

But the problem with this relation is, that `$this->srid` is not available during query building process and can be only there after the actual model is available.

Please help how to overcome this.

Comment: Why is `->where('srid', $this->srid)` in there? I have never seen someone try to define a relation like that.

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly? I bet you overcomplicate things with this backreferencing those tables, and it can be done much easier, so just describe what you need.

Comment: I have a primary table `students` and secondary table `student_revisions` storing multiple revisions for a student. The current revision of student is linked to students by `srid` field in `student` table. `Current` relation/scope returns the revision of student referenced in `srid` column in `student` table. Now I want to load records from `student` table where a particular column in `student_revisions` table of `current` relation/scope matches something. Hope I am clear.

Comment: I think this is not a good idea. What makes `revision` current and why don't you use revisions table for this? Anyway, for this setup, you need `Student belongsTo Revision` and `Revision hasOne Student (current)`, so to fetch the users you need `whereHas`. Answer my question and let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can define it as relation. But what you can do is this:

```
public function current(){
    return $this->revisions()->where('srid', $this->srid)->get();
}
```

This way you can access it by `$student->current()`. You can even go a bit further and make it more `relationship` like:

```
public function current(){
    return $this->revisions()->where('srid', $this->srid);
}

public function getCurrent(){
    return $this->current()->get();
}

protected $appends = array('current');
```

Here we define an accessor for our attribute. [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json) (scroll down to the bottom)

We can then use it like this:

```
$student->current; // retrieves the model
$student->current(); // retrieves an instance of the query builder
```

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. This is absolutely right, the way you have mentioned. Infact, this was working fine, until I got into a scenario, where I have to filter my query based on column from `student_revision` table. Like now I have to load records where `section` in `current` relation is equal to something. I can do it for `revisions` relation with `whereHas` at query building time, but what about `current` scope/relation.